# Compare comma and point(dot) in decimal separator

Tags: c#, silverlight

Can someone help me?
I'm not sure whether it is ignorance or lack of knowledge, but it's really annoying.
What the best way compare this decimal format `123.456,22` and `123,456.22`.

i try this way :

> decimal val1 = 0; decimal val2 = 0;
>
> decimal.TryParse("123,456.22", out val1);
>
> decimal.TryParse("123.456,22", out val2);

if the computer have `123.456,22` format,
i try decimal.TryParse(`123,456.22`, out val1) --> val1 = 0;

now i am using code : Split by "," or "." , i just wondering what easier way to do that.

Comment: How do you want to compare them?

Comment: Could you give us more details about your problem?

Comment: the problem is with the computer format, if there using 123.456,22 i can't using the same method like decimal.TryParse(123,456.22, out val), cause the result will be different.

Comment: It will? Tell me more, or you could just press F1, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx

Comment: yes, the result will different, one of them = 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
decimal d1;
string s1 = "123,456.22";
if (Decimal.TryParse(s1, 
    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ro-RO"), 
    out d1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success: {0} converted into {1} using the ro-RO number format", 
        s1, d1);
}
else if (Decimal.TryParse(s1, out d1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success: {0} converted into {1} using the {2} number format", 
        s1, d1,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
}
    }
}
```

You might find this Wikipedia article interesting: [Decimal mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark).

Comment: i can use this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Decimal.Parse method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z.aspx

```
Decimal.Parse(value);
```

You can use the overloaded method to pass in the Culture (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7xswkc6.aspx)

```
Decimal.Parse(value, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Comment: decimal, not double. Especially if he's doing equality

Comment: the problem is with the computer format, if there using 123.456,22 i can't using the same method like decimal.TryParse(123,456.22, out val), cause the result will be different with decimal.TryParse(123.456,22, out val).

Comment: I think the decimal separators are different, so not sure how this would help ? You should expand on how the comparison could be made !

Comment: now i am using code : Split by "," or "." , i just wondering what easier way to do that.

Comment: Decimal.Parse("123.456,22", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
Decimal.Parse("123,456.22", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));

one of them will failed(Exception).

Comment: Well use Decimal.TryParse or trap the exception and try the other one!

Answer (score 0):

`123.456,22` and `123,456.22` have a different separator, while in one case its point(`.`) in the other case its a comma(`,`) when you just use Parse it would rely on the current culture, so one of them would fail the parse.

In such case you should build up the relevant `NumberFormatInfo` and set it as per your needs for the decimal separator(`NumberDecimalSeparator`) and the thousands separator(`NumberGroupSeparator`)

So you should use TryParse and if that returns false then build your custom one like this and make it available to the Parse as Parameter.

```
// check with TryParse first and if it returns false then try as below
NumberFormatInfo numinf = new NumberFormatInfo();
numinf.NumberDecimalSeparator= ",";
numinf.NumberGroupSeparator= ".";
decimal.Parse("your failed tryparse", numinf);
```

Comment: yes, if users computer have different format ex: (using point), parsing decimal with comma format is imposible.

Comment: if i try this way :
 NumberFormatInfo numinf = new NumberFormatInfo();
            numinf.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
            numinf.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
            decimal aa = decimal.Parse("123.456,22", numinf);
            decimal aaa = decimal.Parse("123,456.22", numinf);

one of them will fail.

Comment: @KizuHikaru Actually you should use a if (decimal.TryParse(....)) and if this fails you handle that by making a custom format which is what you need.

Comment: Thanks, i already use that (handle it if one of them fail) before, just.. i don't want use that(cath exception in the middle of my code) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal d1;
string s1 = "123,456.22";
if (Decimal.TryParse(s1, 
    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ro-RO"), 
    out d1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success: {0} converted into {1} using the ro-RO number format", 
        s1, d1);
}
else if (Decimal.TryParse(s1, out d1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success: {0} converted into {1} using the {2} number format", 
        s1, d1,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
}
    }
}
```

can be used only on console application??